# A vector of maps into a tree

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure

I have a collection that has the following structure [{:a 0} {:b 1} {:c 1} {:d 2} {:e 3} {:f 2}]. Basically, it is a tree, where an element of the vector is a node. What the number signify is the parent-child relationship. So, the element {:a 0} is the master parent (has no parents), while {:b 1}, {:c 1} are childs of {:a 0}. Also, {:d 2} is a child of {:c 1}.

What I want is to construct a list or a vector (doesn't matter at this point) that has the following structure:
[{:a {:b nil :c {:d {:e nil} :f nil}}}].

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you know whether `d` is a child of `b` or `c`?  (Same question for `f`)

Comment: Honestly, I haven't. However, what I was thinking of is to have function that looks into each element, and see if the previous element has a value that is less by one. If so it is its parent. If not then I look into the one that is 2-steps previous, and so forth. But I couldn't build such a function.

Comment: @jas. In the structure that I am interested in, d is a child of c, as it is the nearest element to d.

Comment: @jas. Also f is a child of c, as c is the nearest element that has the lesser value.

Comment: That makes sense --- I can see now that it's building the tree following a depth first path.

Comment: @HassanShahin, I've deleted my answer since I think there may be a problem where it's making an assumption about the order of keys within a map (specifically, assuming the last key in the map was the last one added) but maps don't have defined order! So be careful (and sorry about that).

Comment: @jas. Thanks again. This makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
(fn [xs]
  (loop [[x & rs :as xs] xs
         m   {}
         lvl {}]
    (if (seq xs)
      (let [[k l] (first x)
            p (conj (lvl (dec l) []) k)]
        (recur
          rs
          (assoc-in m p nil)
          (assoc lvl l p)))
      m)))
```

As @jas mentioned we can't rely on key-order of map, so here we use `lvl` map to keep last seen element's path per level.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @HassanShahin Don't forget to accept the answer if it is the right answer

Comment: Very sorry. I voted for the answer, but forgot to accept it. :)

Comment: @Olim-SaidovYour solution worked fine for me when the entries were unique. it fails when they are not. Consider this vector 
[{"html" 0}
 {"body" 1}
 {"aside" 2}
 {"menu" 3}
 {"menuitem" 4}
 {"menuitem" 4}
 {"menuitem" 4}
 {"menuitem" 4}
 {"menuitem" 4}
 {"div" 2}
 {"title" 3}
 {"img" 3}
 {"p" 3}
 {"link" 3}
 {"form" 2}
 {nil 3}
 {"button" 3}
 {"div" 3}
 {"p" 4}
 {"title" 4}
 {"link" 4}
 {"footer" 1}
 {"a" 2}
 {"a" 2}
 {"a" 2}
 {"a" 2}]

The result only contains one "menuitem", and one "a". I wonder if it can be modified to take account of such a case.

Comment: How do you like the result data structure to be?

Comment: @Olim-SaidovFirst: thanks for responding. The resulting nested map should include all the entries, So, it should be
{"html" {"body" {"aside" {"menu" {"menuitem" nil} {"menuitem" nil} {"menuitem" nil} {"menuitem" nil} {"menuitem" nil}},
                 "div" {"title" nil, "img" nil, "p" nil, "link" nil},
                 "form" {"input" nil, "button" nil, "div" {"p" nil, "title" nil, "link" nil}}},
         "footer" {{"a" nil} {"a" nil} {"a" nil} {"a" nil}}}}
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it is not that your algorithm is wrong. It is the map data structure, that is not accepting "many values for the same "key". Am I right?

Comment: I think you'd better open a new question for this.

Comment: no problem. But is there any specific reason to not answer in this thread?

Comment: I didn't open a new question for my case. For the past days I was trying left, right and center for a solution, trying every possible combinations of using loop/recur, walking, postwalk, prewalk functions and nothing worked. There is a simple reason for that, which is (I think) is that my data structure, though valid in some other context, it is not a valid one for clojure. How, on earth, can I differentiate between a "div" inside a certain tag and another "div" inside another tag? There is no way. If the unique identifier for my tags is their "tag" then there is no way this can be done.